# onClick event not triggered on click - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm super new to react and I'm trying to get my onClick working. When the page renders I see that is getting called(multiple times, depending on the number of items in the array) but not on click.

```
const BlogPage = props => {
          const posts = props.data.allContentfulPost.edges;
          const postsStable = props.data.allContentfulPost.edges;
          const categoriesStyle = {
            marginBottom: '8px',
          };

          const filterCategories = category => {
            console.log('here', category);
            // this.posts = this.posts.filter(p => p.catergory === category);
          };.

        return (
        <div style={categoriesStyle}>
            {posts.map(({ node: c }) => (
              <Badge onClick={filterCategories(c.category)}
                  key={c.id}
                  category={c.category}
                  color="#fff">
                  {c.category}
               </Badge>
             ))}
         </div>
        );
    };
```

I have tried:

```
onClick={() => filterCategories(c.category)}
```

and

```
onClick={() => {
                  filterCategories(c.category);
                }}

const Badge = ({ children, category = 'Other', color = '#4a4a4a' }) => {
  return (
    <Container background={pillColor(category)} color={color}>
      {children}
    </Container>
  );
};

Badge.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  category: PropTypes.string,
  color: PropTypes.string,
};
```

> Based on the answers seems like the problem is that Badge is not a
>   HTML element.

Comment: you can pass it explicitly to the `Container` -> `<Container onClick={() => onClick()} />` provided that in your `Container` component there is also a handler for the `onClick` for example `return (<div onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}></div>);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style={categoriesStyle}>
                {posts.map(({ node: c }) => (
                  <span
                    tabIndex="0"
                    key={c.id}
                    onClick={() => filterCategories(c.category)}
                    role="button"
                    onKeyDown={filterCategories}
                  >
                    <Badge value={c.category} category={c.category} color="#fff">
                      {c.category}
                    </Badge>
                  </span>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 4):

The value passed to `onClick` needs to be *a function*.

`filterCategories(c.category)` calls `filterCategories` *immediately* and passes its return value (`undefined` because there is no `return` statement) to `onClick`.

`undefined` is not a function.

Create a function which calls `filterCategories` with the arguments you want (e.g. with `bind`, or just use a function expression or arrow function)  and pass that instead.

---

Additionally, `Badge` is not an HTML element. If your component doesn't pass the `onClick` prop on to an HTML element, it won't do anything in the DOM.

Comment: ````   onClick={() => filterCategories(c.category)} ````? this didn't work

Comment: ohhhhhh that makes sense. A lot!